# Need assistance with list selection listener

Tags: java, textfield, jlist

I'm trying to fill my list selection listener method with code, but I don't know how to approach it. Essentially, I would like for the method to fill multiple text fields when an item is selected from the JList.

My JList looks like this:

```
private JList <String> contactList;
private DefaultListModel<String> model;

//Textfields
comboBookType = new JComboBox(BookType.values());
nameText = new JTextField("", 17);   
authorText = new JTextField("", 17);   
genreText = new JTextField ("", 17);
comboCategory = new JComboBox (readCategory());

//initialize defaultlistmodel and jlist
model = new DefaultListModel <String>();
bookList = new JList (model);
bookList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
bookList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
bookList.setFixedCellHeight (20);
bookList.setFixedCellWidth (130);
bookList.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
JPanel left = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
left.add (new JScrollPane(bookList), BorderLayout.NORTH);
bookList.addListSelectionListener (new ListSelection());

//populating Jlist
class openFileListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

      book.getBooks();
      for (String name : addressBook.getBooks())
      {
        model.addElement(name);
      }
    }
}

//the getBooks() method in my Library class 
public ArrayList<String> getBooks ()
{
  File file;
  Scanner input;
  BookType type;
  ArrayList<String> books;
  ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
  try
  {
    file = new File ("Books.txt");
    input = new Scanner (file);     

    while (input.hasNext())
    {

      String line = input.nextLine ( );
      String [] book = line.split(",");
      type = BookType.valueOf(info[0]);
      String name = book[1];
      b = new Book (type, book[1], book[2], book[3], book[4], info[5]);
      list.add (b);
      information.add (name);

      numOfBooks++;
    }
    input.close ( );
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "File not found");
  }
  return information;
}
```

Here's what I have so far in my list selection listener:

```
private class ListSelection implements ListSelectionListener
{
  public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e) 
  {
    book.getInfo ( );
    int index = bookList.getSelectedIndex ( );
}


//getInfo() method in Library class

public ArrayList<Book> getInfo ()
{
  File file;
  Scanner input;
  BookType type;
  ArrayList<String> book;
  try
  {
    file = new File ("Book.txt");
    input = new Scanner (file);     

    while (input.hasNext())
    {
      String line = input.nextLine ( );
      String [] info = line.split(",");
      type = BookType.valueOf(info[0]);
      String name = info[1];
      Book b = new Contact (type, info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4],info[5]);
      list.add (b);
    }
    input.close ( );
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "File not found");
  }
  return list;
```

It's not much, but I have no ideas on where to go from here.  I know I have to utilize the `index` that I got from from `getSelectedIndex` but I don't know how, please help, thank you.

Comment: Don't use the "Code Snippet" tag. Select your code and use the `{}` button.

Comment: @camickr Thanks, i'll do that from now on.  Just curious, why would I use `{}` over "Code Snippet"?

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to utilize the index that I got from from getSelectedIndex but I don't know how

You would use the index to get the selection item from the `ListModel`:

```
String book = model.getElementAt(index);
```

Or the easier approach is to get the element from the `JList` using the `getSelectedValue()` method:

```
private class ListSelection implements ListSelectionListener
{
    public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;

        //book.getInfo ( );
        //int index = bookList.getSelectedIndex ( );
        String book = bookList.getSelectedValue();
  }
}
```

Now the problem you have is finding the information about the book. You are creating `Book` objects and adding them to an ArrayList. So now you need to create a loop to look at all entries in the ArrayList. Something like:

```
ArrayList<Book> bookInfo = getInfo();

for (Book book: bookInfo)
{
    if (book.equals(book.getTitle())
    {
        authorTextField.setText( book.getAuthor());
        // ... for the rest of the text fields
        return;
    }
}
```

Note a better design would be to read the book info into your class when the class is constructed. This way to don't read the data from the text file every time a selection is made in the JList.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me! Now off to set the combo boxes.